# How to do alignment between objects in header with fancyhdr?

Tags: fancyhdr

[image]
[image]

These two objects are in the header, but I can not align the line so that it is at the bottom of the box.

The line and an image, it has this degrade in the left part, is it possible to make a line with degrade in the latex?

Is it possible to create a makebox that is scaled according to the text and that is 1cm before and after the centralized text?

File "logo"[image]
File "line"[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancyhf{}%

\pagestyle{fancy}

\thispagestyle{plain}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{

\fancyhead[C]{\vspace{3.cm}\includegraphics[width=14.5cm]{Logo/Line}}

\fancyhead[R]{\colorbox{gray}{\makebox[5.0cm]{\textbf{\textcolor{white}{RESEARCH ARTICLE}}}}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\title{\vspace{2cm}Zootherapy and rural livestock farmers in semiarid Patagonia: the transfer of animal aptitudes for health}

\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: 1. We  don't have the logo/line. 2. How  doyou want them to be aligned? Top, centre, bottom?

Comment: The line in relation to the box. Note that it is slightly above the base of the box.

Comment: And how should it be? At the bottom?  Could you post the graphic file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With TikZ and page style `fancyplain`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\fancyhf{}

\fancyhead[C]{%
  \fancyplain
    {%
      \raisebox{-\dp\strutbox}{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[anchor=south east,gray,fill,text=white,font=\bfseries,inner xsep=1cm,outer sep=0pt](n)at(\headwidth,0){RESEARCH ARTICLE};
        \useasboundingbox(0,0)--(n.south east);
        \shade[left color=white,right color=gray](0.3,0)rectangle([yshift=2pt]n.south west);
        \node[anchor=south west] at (0,0){\includegraphics[width=.33\textwidth]{logo}};
      \end{tikzpicture}%
      }%
  }
  {Header on pages with fancy style}% settings for page style fancy
}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}% page number on both plain and fancy pages

\setlength\headheight{16.06573pt}

\title{\vspace{2cm}Zootherapy and rural livestock farmers in semiarid Patagonia: the transfer of animal aptitudes for health}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you esdd. How can I add a logo to stay in the box as in the example figure?

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: Thank tou esdd. If I want to write 3 more lines below the box?

Answer (score 1):

You can do box placement.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{first}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyhead[L]{\maketop}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
}

\newcommand{\maketop}{%
  \leavevmode\smash{\makebox[\textwidth][l]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{ethnologo}\hfill
    \makebox[0pt][r]{\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{ethnoline}}%
    \colorbox{gray}{\bfseries\textcolor{white}{RESEARCH ARTICLE}}%
  }}%
}

\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}

\title{Zootherapy and rural livestock farmers in semiarid Patagonia: 
       the transfer of animal aptitudes for health}

\author{A. Uthor}

\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle\thispagestyle{first}

\end{document}
```

[image]